# Eliminating duplicates.. and more fun

Tags: sql, sql-server

My goal for the query is to calculate the original loan balance of each seperate loan identifier. However, the data I'm using uses each loan identifier multiple times to show the current actual loan balance from different months. Therefore, when I try to calculate the original loan balance, it adds the original loan balance from every time the loan identifier appears. I want to just isolate one original loan balance per loan identifier but I am having trouble doing so. My original idea was to filter the data using a where clause on a unique characterisitc of the loan. For example, filtering the data for just one monthly reporting period. However, the monthly reporting period is from the 'Performance_2011Q4" data and can not be added as a where clause when filtering the 'Original Unpaid Principal Balance' fom the 'Total Acquisition file'. I have tried to join the two tables but I am having trouble trying to filter the search. Does anyone know how to eliminate the duplicates in the list and only calculate one 'Original Unpaid Principal Balance' per loan identifier? Thank you for your help and let me know if you need me to clarify. My code is posted below with the 'where' clause that can't be bound.

SQL Server 2012

```
 SELECT All a.[Loan Identifier]
          ,[Monthly Reporting Period]
          ,[Servicer Name]
          ,[Current Interest Rate]
          ,[Current Actual Unpaid Principal Balance]  
          ,[Loan Age]
          ,[Remaining Months to Legal Maturity]
          ,[Adjusted Remaining Months to Maturity]
          ,[Maturity Date]
          ,b.[ORIGINAL UNPAID PRINCIPAL BALANCE (UPB)]
          ,[Zero Balance Code]
          ,[Zero Balance Effective Date]

            From dbo.Performance_2011Q4 a
      Join dbo.TotalAcquisition b On a.[Loan Identifier] = b. [Loan Identifier]


      Select (sum(convert (float, (dbo.[TotalAcquisition].[ORIGINAL UNPAID PRINCIPAL BALANCE (UPB)])))) from dbo.TotalAcquisition 

 Where dbo.Performance_2011Q4.[Monthly Reporting Period] = '03/01/2013'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've not given us much to go on in terms of sample data, so I'm making some assumptions about your data.  My assumption is that although you have multiple records in TotalAcquisition, the original unpaid principal balance is always the same for a given loan identifier.  If so, something like this should work...

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Loan Identifier], [ORIGINAL UNPAID PRINCIPAL BALANCE (UPB)] FROM TotalAcquisition
```

If that isn't what you're looking for, give us more information like sample rows from each table for one load id.

Comment: Yes, thank you for the clarification. The original unpaid principal balance is the same for a given loan identifier

Answer (score 3):

Use a subquery in a Where clause to filter out all but the earliest record for each loan identifier

```
Select * From dbo.Performance_2011Q4 a
   Join dbo.TotalAcquisition b 
       On a.[Loan Identifier] = b. [Loan Identifier]
Where  [Monthly Reporting Period] = 
   (Select Min([Monthly Reporting Period])
    From dbo.Performance_2011Q4 
    Where [Loan Identifier] = a.[Loan Identifier])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to eliminate the duplicate rows from your query, u can use
[DISTINCT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187831%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) command.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple CTE to eliminate the duplicates with very minor changes to the query;

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT [Loan Identifier], [ORIGINAL UNPAID PRINCIPAL BALANCE (UPB)]
    FROM dbo.TotalAcquisition
)
SELECT All a.[Loan Identifier]
         ,[Monthly Reporting Period]
         ,[Servicer Name]
         ,[Current Interest Rate]
         ,[Current Actual Unpaid Principal Balance]  
         ,[Loan Age]
         ,[Remaining Months to Legal Maturity]
         ,[Adjusted Remaining Months to Maturity]
         ,[Maturity Date]
         ,b.[ORIGINAL UNPAID PRINCIPAL BALANCE (UPB)]
         ,[Zero Balance Code]
         ,[Zero Balance Effective Date]
FROM dbo.Performance_2011Q4 a
JOIN cte b 
  ON a.[Loan Identifier] = b.[Loan Identifier]
```